dnsmasq not answering relayed dhcp requests
I have a dhcp relay configured. It is running on network 10.31.7.0/24. It relaying dhcp requests to a dnsmasq server on 10.18.64.241. In tcpdump I see the requests coming in from 10.31.7.1, but dnsmasq is not answering them. I have configured a dhcp-range for the relayed network
dhcp-range=10.31.7.2,10.31.7.169,255.255.255.0,12h

When I use scapy to craft a packet, then it is working only when I send the packet from an ip address where the dnsmasq server is running (10.18.64.0/24).
The giaddr option is set correctly to 10.31.7.1.
Why is dnsmasq discarding relayed packets that are coming from another subnet? Or am i missing something in the configuration?
scapy script:
from scapy.all import *

fam, hw = get_if_raw_hwaddr("enp0s20f0u3")

# Define the DHCP Discover packet
dhcp_discover_packet = (
    Ether(dst="00:50:56:b3:22:39") /
# working
    IP(src="10.18.64.150", dst="10.18.64.241") /
# not working
    IP(src="10.31.7.1", dst="10.18.64.241") /
    UDP(sport=67, dport=67) /
    BOOTP(hops=1, chaddr=hw, xid=0x22345678, giaddr="10.31.7.1") /
    DHCP(options=[("message-type", "discover"),
        ("server_id", "10.18.64.241"),
        "end"])
)

sendp(dhcp_discover_packet, iface="enp0s20f0u3")

But when I send it from another source ip, that is not on the subnet, then dnsmasq is not responding, not even showing any logs.
What am I missing here?
For some reason the request is answered by dnsmasq.

You should probably share a bit of your dnsmasq configuration.
